# Save API Call with request in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem to save a API call with request in mongodb with mongoose. I am very new in this topic. Need your help!!! Here ist my test.js, how can i solve this problem any ideas. My target is to save the Api call from the url and then update it all 30 min but at the moment i was very happy to save the call. For all help i am very grateful.

````
const request = require('request');
const muenzen = {};
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testingDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection open');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Oh no error');
    console.log(err);
  });

//Create a Schema
const coinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price_btc: Number,
});

//Create a Model with collection coins
const Coin = mongoose.model('Coin', coinSchema);
const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending';

request({ url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    const muenzen = response.body.coins;
  }
});

const coinDB = async () => {
  await Coin.deleteMany({});
  try {
    for (let muenze in muenzen) {
      const coin = new Coin({
        name: muenzen[muenze].item.name,
        price_btc: muenzen[muenze].item.price_btc,
      });
    }
    await coin.save();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
coinDB();```
````

Answer (score 0):

you define `muenzen` as an empty object, it's not an array. I think what you're trying to do is something more like this:

```
const request = require('request');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testingDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection open');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Oh no error');
    console.log(err);
  });

//Create a Schema
const coinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price_btc: Number,
});

//Create a Model with collection coins
const Coin = mongoose.model('Coin', coinSchema);
const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending';

request({ url, json: true }, async (error, response) => {
  try {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      await Coin.deleteMany({});
      for (const muenze of muenzen.coins) {
        const coin = new Coin({
          name: muenze.item.name,
          price_btc: muenze.item.price_btc,
        });
        await coin.save();
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yea you are right. At some point i got desperate and tried everything, but that is not the real bug in this code.